# Mysql subquery returns Subquery returns more than 1 row error

Tags: mysql, database, select, subquery

Say i am having a table and some values like the following.

```
  -----------------------------------------
 | col1    | col2 | col3  | col4  |  col5  |
  ---------|------|-------|-------|--------
 | 6171368 | 1    | TEST  | 12053 | 123456 |
  -----------------------------------------
 | 6171368 | 2    | ABCD  | QWERT |        |
  -----------------------------------------
```

What i want to do is i need to get value of `col5` of 1 row if value of `col5` is empty without using where conditon exclude `where col2 = 2`. When i tried with a query i am getting an error saying

> 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

My query is

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4, 
if (col5 IS NULL or col5 = '' ,
    (
        select col5 from table 
        where col2 = 1 
        group by col1
    ),'')  as col5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a correlated subquery that gets a valid value of `col5` for the row (assuming you have more than one row).

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, 
       (case when col5 IS NULL
             then (select col5
                   from table t2
                   where t2.col1 = t.col1 and
                         t2.col5 is not null
                   limit 1
                  )
        end) as col5
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

From error, we can try something like below:

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4, 
if (col5 IS NULL or col5 = '' ,
    (
        select col5 from table 
        where col2 = 1 
        group by col1 limit 1
    ),'')  as col5
```